# assigning multiple values to different cells in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is probably an easy question, but I couldn't find any simple way to do that. Imagine the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=range(10), columns=range(5))
```

and three lists that contain indices, columns, and values of the defined dataframe that I intend to change:

```
idx_list = [1,5,3,7]  # the indices of the cells that I want to change
col_list = [1,4,3,1]  # the columns of the cells that I want to change
value_list = [9,8,7,6]  # the final value of whose cells`
```

I was wondering if there exist a function in `pandas` that does the following efficiently:

```
for i in range(len(idx_list)):
    df.loc[idx_list[i], col_list[i]] = value_list[i]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `.values`

```
df.values[idx_list,col_list]=value_list
df
Out[205]: 
     0    1    2    3    4
0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
1  NaN    9  NaN  NaN  NaN
2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3  NaN  NaN  NaN    7  NaN
4  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    8
6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7  NaN    6  NaN  NaN  NaN
8  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Or another way less efficient

```
updatedf=pd.Series(value_list,index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([idx_list,col_list])).unstack()
df.update(updatedf)
```

Comment: simple and fast! according to `%timeit', more than 50 times faster than the simple loop!

Comment: @arash just one think need to mentioned , .values method is equal to .iloc if you do need . loc equivalent using 2rd method .

Answer (score -1):

try df.applymap() function, you can use lambda to do your required operations.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, from the performance perspective, lambda and the simple loop are almost identical.